# MySQL : Updating table with values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sql-update

Here I'm trying to update my users table with values from the transactions table in MySQL.

```
UPDATE users 
SET users.balance=(users.balance+(SUM(transaction.t_qty * transactions.share_price))) 
 FROM users,transactions 
 WHERE users.user_email=transactions.user_email;
```

[image: Transactions Table]

[image: Users Table]

Above are the two tables I am using for this query.
Kindly help me resolve this issue :)

I was expecting the values to get updated, it gave me a syntax error which I'm unable to rectify.

[image: Error Message]

Kindly help me resolve this issue :)

Comment: UPDATE have no FROM clause in MySQL. Study [UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html), "Multiple-table syntax".

Comment: How else can I form that query, I saw another website where they were using from so I assumed that would work, I'm still a beginner in MySQL and I'm trying to learn

Comment: *I saw another website where they were using from so I assumed that would work* (#1) Do not see third websites, study official documentation. Firstly at least. (#2) You saw SQL Server (MS SQL) specific syntax which is not applicable to MySQL.

Comment: after select ,you have to write just one table name

Answer (score 1):

First aggregate in `transactions` to get each user's `balance` and then use a join of `users` to the results of the aggregation.

This is the correct syntax for MySql:

```
UPDATE users AS u
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT user_email,
         SUM(t_qty * share_price) AS balance
  FROM transactions
  GROUP BY user_email 
) AS t
ON t.user_email = u.user_email;
SET u.balance = t.balance;
```